# Working with dataframe / matrix to create an input for sklearn & Tensorflow

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, sklearn-pandas, google-cloud-datalab

I am working with pandas / python /numpy / datalab/bigQuery to generate an input table for machine learning processing. The data is genomic - and right now, I am working with small subset of
174 rows
12430 columns

The column names are extracted from bigQuery `(df_pik3ca_features = bq.Query(std_sql_features).to_dataframe(dialect='standard',use_cache=True))` 
at the same way, the row names are extracted: `samples_rows = bq.Query('SELECT sample_id FROM`speedy-emissary-167213.pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_features_values_step_3`GROUP BY sample_id')`

what would be the easiest way to create a dataframe / matrix with named rows and columns that were extracted.

I explored the dataframes in pandas and could not find the way to pass the names as parameter.

for empty array, I was able to find the following (numpy) with no names:

```
a = np.full([num_of_rows, num_of_columns], np.nan)
a.columns
```

I know R very well (if there is no other way - I hope that I can use it with datalab)

any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your column names and row names stored in lists then you can just use `.loc` to select the exact rows and columns you desire. Just make sure that the row names are in the index. You might need to do `df.set_index('sample_id')` to put the correct row name in the index.

Assuming the rows and columns are in variables `row_names` and `col_names`, do this.

```
df.loc[row_names, col_names]
```

Comment: thank you. the code that i used (for anyone who might be interested): import pandas as pd
c = list(df_pik3ca_features['PIK3CA_features'])
r = list(df_rows['sample_id'])
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=c,index=r)
data.head()